# Creating Hashset object in method decreases the stack memory in java

Tags: java

I have read that only primitives are stored in Stack memory and objects are stored in Heap memory. In the following program I am recursively calling a method to check the maximum stack size before stackoverflow error occurs.

```
public class MaxStackSize {
static int i =0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1();
}

public static void method1()
{
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
    method1();
}
}
```

Here the max output for 'i' is 53481.

If I add HashSet object to the method and populate it:

```
public class MaxStackSize {
static int i =0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1();
}
public static void method1()
{
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("one");
    set.add("two");
    set.add("three");
    set.add("four");
    set.add("five");
    set.add("six");
    set.add("seven");
    set.add("eight");
    set.add("nine");

    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
    method1();
}
}
```

The max output for 'i' is 25403.

For both the cases VM arg is -Xss5m.

If only primitives are stored on stack why does the stacksize decrease when object of HashSet is created.

Comment: you are calling recursively your `method1()`. that is why it increasing, not the `HashSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives are stored on the stack. So are local variables which are object *references*.  The `HashSet` you instantiate goes on the heap but the reference to each `HashSet`, variable `set`, goes on the stack.

Comment: Hi Sir, do you mean the `set.add()` method invocation ? Im confused too. thanks

Comment: No, `HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();`  Each invocation takes up space in the stack to store the value of `set`.

Comment: As @LKTN.25 pointed out, there would eventually be a stack overflow regardless of the reference variable.

Comment: So I will not be erase in the stack in a recursively way on the method?

Comment: The infinite recursion means NONE of the references gets deleted until the program crashes out of stack space.

Comment: Thank you Jim for the answer. If I add "long ref = 0x33d444; ref = ref + 0x33d445;"  instead of HashSet mimicking reference to a memory address OR if I write only HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); but don't add any string in it, then the max value of 'i' is around 50098. This is a big difference from 25403. May be JVM optimizes and discards the Set or long as it is not used. Please advise.